# Finding the index/location of an object inside an array without looping through all its contents

Tags: objective-c, ios

Take the code below:

```
 NSPredicate *predicateSource = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF = %d",5];
 NSArray *filteredArraySource = [[[self.myArray copy]autorelease] filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicateSource];
```

`myArray` (`NSMutableArray`) contains 100 integers (numbers 1-100 in random order). What I'd like to do is somehow find out which index contains the number `5` without looping through each object in the array. The above code only extracts the object and places it into an array.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I think there are methods to get the index - did you check the documentation ?

Comment: I think that NSArray is a wrapper for a linear array, so with every method you can use, you will always have to scan the whole array (independently from who does it).
And with 100 numers array it's not a problem sobig.

Then, what if you have more than 1 item containing the number "5" , or more  generically the Value "X" ?

Comment: Luckily in my case, there will never be a duplicate (each is unique).

Comment: @Kappa: You're (almost certainly) wrong. `NSArray` is opaque, but seems to be a front-end for a hash table: http://ridiculousfish.com/blog/posts/array.html

Comment: @IuliusCæsar probably not linear.. but very strange that beginning insertion graph.. seems like Std C++ vector, even worst. Anyway something like BST would be faster both in walking,searching and insertion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `indexOfObjectPassingTest:`. If you need to use `NSPredicate`, call your predicate's `evaluateWithObject:` inside the block; otherwise, simply check the object's integer value to be `5`.

Comment: I was working with an `NSMutableArray` and didn't think to just copy it into an `NSArray`. Thanks! (Will accept after "6 minutes")

Comment: @sooper You do not need to copy `NSMutableArray` into `NSArray` to make it work: whatever works for `NSArray`, works for `NSMutableArray` as well.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `indexOfObject:`.